# Is it possible to upload test data files with folders in to Blazemeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, blazemeter

I have created a JMeter project with the below structure.

```
Project folder
|-JMeterProject.jmx
|
|-environments-folder
|  |-environment1.properties
|  |-environment2.properties
|
|-data-folder
  |-data1.csv
  |-data2.csv
```

When I try to add this project in to blazemeter, I could not find a way upload the folder.

**UPDATE:** I retrieve the files using following script

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}\environments-folder\\${environment}.properties
```

Of Course I can change the Jmeter project to refer files in the same folder and copy all in the fame level. But I want to keep the structure the same for various other reasons.

I read through the documentation , but non explains this kind of data file management.

I this something possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [Shared Folders](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002087717-Shared-Folders-Shared-Folders) feature

Going forward I would recommend opening a [BlazeMeter Support Ticket](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-open-a-support-ticket-) for this sort of questions as BlazeMeter team knows their product much better than anyone here.

Comment: Thanks @dmitri-t, I tried the shared folders. They worked for the dependency jars. Also I have created the folders with the same names as the project structure. I keep getting the error saying the files are not found.

Comment: I have logged a blazemeter support ticket for this... Waiting for their response atm.